# Proof related to existence of root in an odd degree polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, proof-explanation, roots

Let n be odd and $a_0, a_1, \dots; a_{n-1}  \in \mathbb{R}$. Define $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$f(x) = x_n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1x + a_0$.

How do I prove that if $x_1 \gt max\{1, 2 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |a_i|\}$, $f(x_1)>0$?

Progress: I was able to prove the following:

$|\frac{a_{n-1}}{x} + \dots + \frac{a_0}{x}| \lt \frac{1}{2}$ if $x=max$ $\{{1, 2 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |a_i|}\}$ and also

$|\frac{a_{n-1}}{x} + \dots + \frac{a_0}{x}| \lt \frac{1}{|x|} (|a_{n-1}| + \dots + |a_1| + |a_0|)$ if $x=max$ $\{{1, 2 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |a_i|}\}$

Comment: Hint: if $x>1$, $f(x) \geq x^{n-1}(x-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{|a_i|})$.

Comment: Hi, how did you get $f(x)  \geq x^{n − 1}(x − \sum _{i=0}^{n-1} |ai|)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If$$x_1>\max\left\{1,2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|a_i|\right\},\tag1$$then $x_1>1$, and therefore $\left|x_1^{\,n}\right|=|x_1|^n>|x_1|$. So,\begin{align}|f(x_1)|&=\left|x_1^{\,n}+a_{n-1}{x_1}^{\,n-1}+\cdots+a_1x_1+a_0\right|\\&=|x_1|^n\left\lvert1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x_1}+\cdots+\frac{a_1}{x_1^{\,n-1}}+\frac{a_0}{x_1^{\,n}}\right\rvert\\&\geqslant|x_1|^n\left|1-\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}{x_1}+\cdots+\frac{a_1}{x_1^{\,n-1}}+\frac{a_0}{x_1^{\,n}}\right|\right|\\&\geqslant|x_1|^n\left(1-\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}{x_1}+\cdots+\frac{a_1}{x_1^{\,n-1}}+\frac{a_0}{x_1^{\,n}}\right|\right)\\&\geqslant|x_1|^n\left(1-\left(\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|x_1|}+\cdots+\frac{|a_1|}{|x_1|^{n-1}}+\frac{|a_0|}{|x_1|^n}\right)\right)\\&\geqslant|x_1|^n\left(1-\left(\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|x_1|}+\cdots+\frac{|a_1|}{|x_1|}+\frac{|a_0|}{|x_1|}\right)\right)\\&\geqslant|x_1|^n\left(1-\frac12\right)\text{ (by $(1)$)}\\&>0.\end{align}